# How to read space separated text for creating graphs using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have data in following format in train.txt where each row represents authors having an edge(paper written) together. FOr eg, first row represents author 0 and 356 having a paper. There may be multiple papers written by same group of authors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKS95.png)

I want to read this text in such a way that I am able to draw graph using networkx for further analysis. using readline() command is reading each line as string

[Click here to see train data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKS95.png)

Comment: After getting a line with `readline()` you can use the split to split the line into tokens at spaces. To convert a line into a list of integers you can do `[int(x) for x in line.split(' ')]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nx.read_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html). The default delimiter is whitespace. Hence, the call should do the work (and already cast the nodes to integers)

```
nx.read_edgelist("train.txt", nodetype=int)
```